# HDC memory leak

Tags: c++, winapi

Not sure why but im using Deleaker plugin to detect memory leaks.
in my code in debug build its saying i have amemory leak at `GetDC` 
Then in release build it is saying i have a leak at `CreateCompatibleDC`

are these real leaks or false?
my delete objects are called when my class closes.

```
    HDC hdc = GetDC(_hWnd);
    _hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(_hdcMem, _hBitmap);

    while (_execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) 
    {
        func();

        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, _Width, _Height, _hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    }

    SelectObject(_hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteDC(_hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hbmOld);
    DeleteObject(_hBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdc);
```

Comment: Did you try it with Valgrind as well? It's not definitive if it's reported leaking by two tools, but it will give you a better idea.

Comment: didnt know about that one will give it ago thanks

Comment: I've never heard of Deleaker, but I know many swear by Valgrind. I've still had Valgrind report false positives (especially in multithreaded applications), but overall it's a fine tool.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `ReleaseDC()` to free the HDC returned by `GetDC()`.

Do not delete the `hbmOld` that `SelectObject()` returned.  Just select it back into the HDC and let `ReleaseDC()` handle its deletion.

Comment: thanks missed the releaseDC still getting same leaks after it

Answer (score 3):

After `GetDC`, you must call `ReleaseDC`—*not* `DeleteDC`. `DeleteDC` is only used with `CreateCompatibleDC`. This is all spelled out in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871.aspx) in case you forget.

Also, you are incorrectly cleaning up your device context. The reason you save the handles to the old objects is so that you can *reselect* them into the DC. You cannot delete them! Objects that are selected into a device context cannot be deleted—they are in use. (If you were checking the return values of these API functions, you would know that, because they would have returned an error.)

The code should look like this:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(_hWnd);

_hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(_hdcMem, _hBitmap);

while (_execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) 
{
    func();

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, _Width, _Height, _hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

SelectObject(_hdcMem, hbmOld);
DeleteObject(_hBitmap);
DeleteDC(_hdcMem);

ReleaseDC(_hWnd, hdc);
```

It is unclear to me why you are using global variables for `_hdcMem` and `_hBitmap` when their scope is limited to this single bit of code. You create them at the top, and destroy them at the bottom, so they are useless outside of this code. You should limit their scope to just this section of the code, too. Being able to reason about the lifetime of objects/variables is key to stomping out memory leaks.

Note that using a library that wraps these native resources up in an [RAII fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (constructor acquires; destructor releases) would be a wonderful idea. It not only frees you from having to remember the details of how to clean up each time, but it also ensures that your code is exception-safe. If `func()` were to throw here, you would certainly have a memory leak. That is something a *really good* static analyzer would tell you as well.

Comment: im using global variables for _hdcMem and _hBitmap because i use them else where, must be my leak detector because its still saying there is a leak there

Comment: You do not need global variables unless you are reusing the *values* stored in those variables. You can create multiple variables, it doesn't do any good to reuse globals. As far as the leaks, it is possible that (1) your leak detector is reporting the possibility of leaks if an exception is thrown, as I pointed out in my answer, or (2) that you have other code in your project that is using GDI objects and therefore subject to leaks. Presumably you haven't shown *all* of the code...

Comment: Despite what the docs say, I've had to call DeleteDC after GetDC otherwise I'd get memory leaks too. I typically do Get, Release, and Delete

Comment: The docs are absolutely correct, @mikew... You should *never* call DeleteDC after calling GetDC. Get is paired with Release; Create is paired with Delete. This is because "Get" is actually retrieving a handle to a device context from a pool of DCs managed by the system. You are thus invoking undefined behavior, by deleting a DC out from underneath the system. I recommend a better memory profiler.